# Entity Framework Core: Extend Entity without partial

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have to extend current database entity (`Foo`) to include new fields. Sounds easy but I struggle with solution. Problem is, I'm not able to create a partial class for `Foo` because it's part of a dll which I'm using. And there is no way how I could request modify `Foo` (or do it by my own) as I wish.

My project structure is similar to this:

```
// unmodifiable because part of dll
class Foo 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

// unmodifiable because part of dll
interface IFooContext 
{
     DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
}

class FooContext: DbContext, IFooContext 
{
     DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
}
```

With my limited knowledge of .net, what I tried, was create class `Bar` what extends `Foo` and expected it would be enough to implement `IFooContext` with extended class `Bar`.

Below you can see, but it will end up with error, because C# doesn't allow use extended class interchangeable for parent.

```
class Bar: Foo 
{
     string Description { get; set; } //new field
}

class FooLoader: DbContext, IFooContext 
{
     DbSet<Bar> Foo; //error because DbSet<Foo> required
}
```

What I could do, is create property `DbSet<Bar> Bar { get; set; }` inside `FooLoader`, but then I will end up with two almost identical database tables: Foo and Bar.

So I made modification and created class `Bar` which will contain `FooId`. It results into two tables, where `Bar` table has a reference to `Foo`.

```
class Bar 
{
     int Id { get; set; }

     Foo Foo { get; set; }
     int FooId { get; set; }

     string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Both cases, will create a new table what I'm not sure, if is what I looking for. But is there any other way how to do it and have new fields included in base class/table?

Comment: when you don't have access to dll, then why to extend it? you could create Bar model entirely (including the properties of Foo) in your context right?

Comment: Because its part of framework guts which depends on IFooLoader implementation and what I have to do, is provide implementation of it. But in same time I need new parameters for my use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code first approach gives you at least 3 options to map your (inheritance hierarchy) entities to tables:

1. [Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)
2. [Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)
3. [Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines)

What you need is the 1st approach, which will map your base class and hieratances to one table, but an additional column ("Discriminator" as default name) will be added to identify their `Type`, which column will be used to revert to its own type when you query the full row from database. and most important: the 1st approach also gives best performance, comparing the other 2 approachs.

here are good posts where you can find implementation:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-3.1
3. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy

it is simply like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ....

    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("FooType")
            .HasValue<Foo>(nameof(Foo))
            .HasValue<Bar>(nameof(Bar))
            .HasValue<Other>(nameof(Other));
    ...
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .HasDiscriminator<int>("FooType")
        .HasValue<Foo>(1)
        .HasValue<Bar>(2)
        .HasValue<Other>(3);
```